# How to select the identified cell by using range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim coname, WHAT_TO_FIND As String
    Dim i As Integer
    totalRow = Application.CountA(Range("c:c")) - 1
    i = 2
    While i <= totalRow
    coname = Sheet20.Cells(i, "A") 
    i = i + 1
    WHAT_TO_FIND = coname
    sheets("Sheet21").Select 
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set FoundCell = ws.Range("D:D").Find(what:=WHAT_TO_FIND, lookat:=xlWhole)

    wend

// in sheet20 I have limited number of comapny names list
// in sheet21 I have the data with n number of company names
```

Please let me know how to select that particular cell which is found in sheet21.

Answer (score 1):

Try and avoid using `.Select` [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

However to answer your question, paste this code below

```
Set FoundCell = ws.Range("D:D").Find(what:=WHAT_TO_FIND, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then FoundCell.Select
```

I would rather use this

```
Set FoundCell = ws.Range("D:D").Find(what:=WHAT_TO_FIND, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    With FoundCell
        '
        '~~> Do something
        '
    End With
End If
```